# Solving a PDE with Boundary and Initial conditions with separation of variables?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have this problem:

[image]

I know how to solve this problems with separation of variables, but I'm in trouble with this specific equation because of the initials conditions.
I'm expecting to have something like that:
$$X(x)=a\cos(ax)+b\sin(ax)$$Where $\lambda=\alpha^{2}$ a costant.
And for the temporal part $$T(t)=ce^{-\lambda t}$$
I don't know how to use the initial condition specified for the first derivative of the themporal part. Could someone help me? Thank you, as always!!!.

Comment: Please include the equation as MathJax instead of using a picture. Your solution for the temporal part is not correct. This equation is of 2nd order in time, there should be two constants there as well

Comment: Thank you for you fast reply. I have solved this problem with your hint! I have posted my last rpoblem with PDE, and I have used MathJax. Sorry if I hadn't used it on this post but it was just question of time. I'll never make this mistake again. Thank you, If you want you can come to see my latest post. Have a nice evening :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try separated solutions $X(x)T(t)$, then you end up with
$$
                        X''(x)=\lambda X(x),\;\; T''(t)=\lambda T(t) \\
                            X(-\pi)=X(\pi)=0.
$$
One of the problems with such problems is that there a scaling degree a freedom, but you can eliminate that scale factor by choose $X$ so that $X'(-\pi)=1$. That also makes the the eigenfunctions have a power series expansion in $\lambda$, which is a good thing. So, start by solving
$$
             X''(x)=\lambda X,\;\;\; X'(-\pi)=1,\; X(-\pi)=0 \\
       \implies X(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}(x+\pi)).
$$
The eigenvalues are then determined by the following equation in $\lambda$:
$$
        0=X(\pi)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\sin(2\pi\sqrt{\lambda})=0.
$$
So $\lambda=0$ is not an eigenvalue because the above equation remains valid in the limiting case as $\lambda\rightarrow 0$ and gives $2\pi$, which is non-zero; this follows because of how the eigenfunctions have a power series expansion in $\lambda$ when normalized. In fact, you can get the special case solution for $\lambda=0$ as a limit of that power series in $\lambda$ by using L'Hospital's rule:
$$
           X(x) = x+\pi.
$$
Proper normalization always gets rid of the pesky special cases; they become limiting cases in $\lambda$. The above is a solution of the equation $X''=0X$ with $X(-\pi)=0$ and $X'(-\pi)=1$.

The zeros of $\sin$ in the complex plane are where
$$
              2\pi\sqrt{\lambda} = n\pi \\
                 \lambda = \frac{n^2}{4},\;\;\; n=1,2,3,\cdots.
$$
The corresponding eigenfunctions are
$$        X_n = \sin(\frac{n}{2}(x+\pi)),\;\;\; n=1,2,3,\cdots \\
      T_n = A_n\cos(\frac{n}{2}t)+B_n\sin(\frac{n}{2}t).
$$
The full solution is
$$
             u(t,x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}T_n(t)X_n(x).
$$
The constants $A_n$, $B_n$ are determined by the initial conditions

Comment: Hi and thank you for your reply. It's an interesting reasoning. But the initial conditions on this specific problem give us these compatibilities conditions:
$$X(-\pi)=X(\pi)=0$$
And these are different from yours (you have considered the first derivative of $X$).
So, maybe it would be easier..

Comment: @muserock92 : Sorry about that. I misread and will change it.

Comment: No problem, I was pleased to observe this case too. Never stop learning, especially for me that I have a long way to go.

Comment: @muserock92 : I like to tell people about this normalization trick because it gets rid of special cases, and it does not seem to be widely known. And it gets rid of annoying degrees of freedom that are artificial, often replacing two constants by one.

Comment: I was thnking about this other idea. It's an heat equation.
$$\frac{X''}{X}=\frac{T''}{T}=\lambda$$ Let $\lambda=-\alpha^{2}<0$ to simplify the algebra. So:
$$X(x)=a\cos(\alpha x)+b\sin(\alpha x)$$
$$T(t)=c\cos(\alpha t)+d\sin(\alpha t)$$
Applying the conditions
$$X(-\pi)=a\cos(-\pi \alpha)+b\sin(-\pi \alpha)=-a=0$$with $$\alpha=k\in\mathbb N$$
$$X(\pi)=...$$same results.
So
$$X_{n}=b\sin(k^{2}x)$$
For the temporal part:

$$\frac{T''}{T}=-k^{2}$$
$$T=c\sin(k^{2}t)+d\cos(k^{2}t)$$
Now I can use the initial condition to find the constants. What do you think about it? Thank you.

Comment: @muserock92 : In what I wrote, $X_n(x)=\sin(n\pi x/2),\;\; n=1,2,3,\cdots$ works because it's only a constant multiplier from what I had written. Then I believe you need $T(t)=C\cos(n t/2)+D\sin(nt/2)$. I don't think you really have the square of an integer in the argument beause all you need is $X_n(-\pi)=X_n(\pi)=0$.

Comment: Yes, there was a mistake.
The correct one is:
$$T=c\sin(kt)+d\cos(kt)$$
That's looks like yours but not exactly the same thing, so I don't know if my idea could work as well as your. Thank you.

Comment: @muserock92  Whatever the scale factors in $T$, the scale factors will be the same in $X$ because $T''=\lambda T$ and $X''=\lambda X$ use the same $\lambda$.

Comment: Thanks, it was another error. My final result should be:
$$U(x,t)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_{k}\sin(kx)\cos(kt)sin(kt) $$
Have I maybe consider to add $\cos(kx)$ term in the sum? Thank you.